# how to create a downloadable csv file in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I use python Appengine. I'm trying to create a link on a webpage, which a user can click to download a csv file. How can I do this?

I've looked at csv module, but it seems to want to open a file on the server, but appengine doesn't allow that.

I've looked at remote_api, but it seems that its only for uploading or downloading using app config, and from account owner's terminal.

Any help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/csv'
writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
writer.writerow(['foo','foo,bar', 'bar'])
```

Put it in your handler's get method. When user requests it, user's browser will download the list content automatically.

Got from: [generating a CSV file online on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164686/generating-a-csv-file-online-on-google-app-engine)

Comment: Hey, I'm getting an error that "self" is not defined. What if my get handler is not a class? Do you have any sample code of how this can work?

Answer (score 6):

Pass a `StringIO` object as the first parameter to `csv.writer`; then set the content-type and content-disposition on the response appropriately (probably "text/csv" and "attachment", respectively) and send the `StringIO` as the content.