# generating a CSV file online on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I am using Google App Engine (python), I want my users to be able to download a CSV file generated using some data from the datastore (but I don't want them to download the whole thing, as I re-order the columns and stuff).

I have to use the csv module, because there can be cells containing commas. But the problem that if I do that I will need to write a file, which is not allowed on Google App Engine

What I currently have is something like this:

```
    tmp = open("tmp.csv", 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(tmp)
    writer.writerow(["foo", "foo,bar", "bar"])
```

So I guess what I would want to do is either to handle cells with commas.. or to use the csv module without writing a file as this is not possible with GAE..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a way to use the CSV module on GAE! Here it is:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/csv'
writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)

writer.writerow(["foo", "foo,bar", "bar"])
```

This way you don't need to write any files

Comment: Hey there - where do you place this code? I know it needs to be in a class since you're using `self`, but my `main.py` and other files aren't currently written in classes.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a complete example of using the [Python CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in GAE. I typically use it for creating a csv file from a gql query and prompting the user to save or open it.

```
import csv

class MyDownloadHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    q = ModelName.gql("WHERE foo = 'bar' ORDER BY date ASC")
    reqs = q.fetch(1000)

    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=studenttransreqs.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
```

create row labels

```
    writer.writerow(['Date', 'Time','User' ])
```

iterate through query returning each instance as a row

```
    for req in reqs:
        writer.writerow([req.date,req.time,req.user])
```

Add the appropriate mapping so that when a link is clicked, the file dialog opens

```
('/mydownloadhandler',MyDownloadHandler),
```

Comment: Hey there - where would all of this code go? I'm struggling to figure out where to place it. In my main.py that has all of my routes, or my backend code file that does all of the processing and creates the list I want to export?

Answer (score 4):

```
import StringIO

tmp = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(tmp)

writer.writerow(["foo", "foo,bar", "bar"])
contents = tmp.getvalue()

tmp.close()
print contents
```