# Create downloadable csv file in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv

I'm trying to do the exact same thing as this SO question- [how to create a downloadable csv file in appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766199/how-to-create-a-downloadable-csv-file-in-appengine?rq=1), but in Java. Right now I have `CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(response.getWriter(), '\t');` but am not sure how to proceed since I have a `java.util.List` of queries, not an array.

Comment: Do you need your List-object to be an array instead? What is the overall question here?

Comment: I would like to generate the csv file from the list object of entities from my query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the class of your "values" you might have to:

1. Loop the entire list and convert to a String accordingly, for instance,

   String[] array = new String[values.size()];

   for (i = 0 ; i < values.size() ; i ++) {

   array[i] = String.valueOf(values.get(i));

   }

   (Be careful with NPEs), or
2. If the values are String already, convert the List to an array using:

   List values = ...;

   String[] array = values.toArray(new String[values.size]);